# Alternative to setTimeout for Angular lifecycles

Tags: angular, rxjs, settimeout

my question comes from a situation (I've already solved it but I'm looking for good practices). I have an input that automatically fetch an array from an API. Then run an `*ngFor` with this array to display the options and focus the first one, but here is my problem: I have to use a setTimeout so angular gets the rendered option otherwise I get its undefined. I have been using this, but I know that using setTimeout is not good because for a re-watch of all the states, my question is what is the best way to do this? It is with rxjs?

Parent Component

```
@Component({
  template:`
    <generic-child-component></child-component>
  `
})
export class ParentComponent implements OnInit{
  @ViewChild(ChildGenericComponent)child: ChildGenericComponent
  delaySubject: Subject<string> = new Subject();

  contructor (private apiService: ApiService){}

  ngOnInit(){
    this.delaySubject.pipe(
      debounceTime(2500),
    ).subscribe(query=>{
      this.apiService.get(query).subscribe(fetchedData=>{
        this.child.fetchedOptions = fetchedData
        //Here I want to put a focus in the first Object
        //but i need to make a setTimeout to get the rendered option in the child component
        setTimeout(() => {
          this.child.optionsInputs.first.nativeElement.focus() //If this its outside this setTimeout the child.optionsInputs = undefined
        })
      })
    })
  }

  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    this.child.form.controls['filter'].subscribe(query=>this.delaySubject.next(query))
  }

}
```

ChildComponent

```
import { Component, ElementRef, QueryList, ViewChildren } from "@angular/core";
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup} from "@angular/forms";

@Component({
  selector:'generic-child-component',
  template:`
    <form [formGroup]="form">
    <input [formControlName]="'filter'" type="text">
    </form>
    <div *ngFor="let option of fetchedOptions">
      <input #optionsInputs >
      {{option}}
    </div>
  `
})
export class GenericDelayComponent {

  @ViewChildren('optionsInputs')optionsInputs:QueryList<ElementRef>

  constructor(private fBuilder:FormBuilder){}

  fetchedOptions=[]

  form: FormGroup = this.fBuilder.group({
    filter:[null]
  })

}
```

Comment: _setTimeout_ is never a good idea in such scenarios - What happens if the API takes longer to process the request/ to answer? Are you using `subscribe()` in your _component.ts_ ?

Comment: Initialize the array to empty array. So, the *ngFor will not throw any errors. Instead of using setTimeout use the option 1 mentioned by JeffryHouser.

Comment: @iLuvLogix I'm using setTimeout after i have the fetched data. I would try to provide an example  code.

Answer (score 3):

> I have to use a setTimeout so angular gets the rendered option
> otherwise i get its undefined

Without code, it is tough to answer this question, and I'm unclear how using `setTimeout()` is used to prevent Angular from rendering undefined variables.  But, a few thoughts:

**Option 1**: Default the results.

An example might be like this:

```
export class AppComponent  implements OnInit {
  myResults = [];

  ngOnInit(): void {
     myService.loadData.subscribe((resultsFromServer) => {
          this.myResults = resultsFromServer;
     });
  }
}
```

This is what I most commonly use.

**Option 2**:  Use [Resolvers](https://angular.io/api/router/Resolve) to load data before the component is initialized.  A resolver is, basically, some code that runs before the route is loaded, and before the component is initialized.  There is an example in the docs, so I won't repeat here.

**Option 3**: If you REALLY need `setTimeout()` functionality, you can use the [rxjs delay](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/utility/delay) as part of an observable chain:

Generically, that might be like this:

```
of(([])).pipe(
 delay(6000)
).subscribe((results) => { 
// do something
 });
```

Comment: Hii, thanks for the answer, i would provide code but i figure it wasnt that much important, what i mean with the setTimeout is not that I need the timer, it was the solution to make an async function so it gets in the next cicle and i can access the children. I do know of resolvers, but I'm rendering the data in the same view. Thanks, i would try to make an example of the code I have.

Comment: I updated the question with some code.

Comment: I only took a quick glance.  It looks like you're trying to update a child's children from the parent.  The approach breaks encapsulation a few levels, because the parent needs to know the implementation details of the child.  
The parent should ideally call a method on the child; which should handle setting the focus.  Then you could set a flag in the method, and tie into the lifecycle methods to set focus after the view is refreshed.

Comment: Yap, that worked like a charm, thanks I appreciate it. I updated the question with the solution following this.

Comment: @RigolMuhammadAli I'm glad I was able to help. I recommend you post an answer your own question, instead of adding your solution to the original question.  It works better for the way Stack Overflow is structured.

Comment: oh yeah, when I updated it, I thought it was bad. Thanks for the tips.

Answer (score 1):

**My solution following @JeffryHouser 's answer:**
Parent Component

```
@Component({
  template:`
    <generic-child-component></child-component>
  `
})
export class ParentComponent implements OnInit{
  @ViewChild(ChildGenericComponent)child: ChildGenericComponent
  delaySubject: Subject<string> = new Subject();

  contructor (private apiService: ApiService){}

  ngOnInit(){
    this.delaySubject.pipe(
      debounceTime(2500),
    ).subscribe(query=>{
      this.apiService.get(query).subscribe(fetchedData=>{
        this.child.setOptions(fetchedData)
        })
      })
    })
  }

  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    this.child.form.controls['filter'].subscribe(query=>this.delaySubject.next(query))
  }

}
```

ChildComponent

```
import { Component, ElementRef, QueryList, ViewChildren } from "@angular/core";
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup} from "@angular/forms";

@Component({
  selector:'generic-child-component',
  template:`
    <form [formGroup]="form">
    <input [formControlName]="'filter'" type="text">
    </form>
    <div *ngFor="let option of fetchedOptions">
      <input #optionsInputs >
      {{option}}
    </div>
  `
})
export class GenericDelayComponent {

  @ViewChildren('optionsInputs')optionsInputs:QueryList<ElementRef>

  constructor(private fBuilder:FormBuilder){}
  
  ngAfterViewInit(){
    if(this.fetchedOptions.length){
      this.child.optionsInputs.first.nativeElement.focus()
    }  
  }  

  fetchedOptions=[]

  setOptions(options:[]{
    this.fetchedOptions = options
  }

  form: FormGroup = this.fBuilder.group({
    filter:[null]
  })

}
```